# How to generate a range of random numbers in python without repetition

Tags: python, random, seed

I would like to generate random numbers in the range (0..."MAX"). I would like to make a loop such that every time going through the loop a new unique random number is generated (should not repeat). The loop will continue a total of "MAX" times. There should be "MAX" number of random numbers generated in total. When sorted, the values should be 0..."MAX"; no repetition.

Restrictions: 
- Assume MAX is much larger than int. (no memory to store all number permutations in memory)

My proposed solution:
If I seed the generator from 0...MAX would that allow me to print every unique number between 0 and MAX as in the below function? Assume there's no space to store all numbers and shuffling them.

```
for x in range (0, MAX):
    random.seed(x)
    num=random.randint(0, MAX)
    print("seed = ",x, "    random number = ", num)
```

If the answer for the above is yes then would this generation be reversible (can i get the seed from the random number)? In which case would this be considered a kind of block cipher that is if the seed (key) and the range is the same length?

Comment: Can you explain what output you want?  Your code is invalid because `randint` requires arguments.  Also, nothing in your code will prevent repetitions.  Why are you seeding the generator anew on each iteration?

Comment: Tnx. Fixed. I want a new random number in the range of 0...Max for each iteration and it must not repeat with previous numbers. I'm seeding it because i'm guessing that a unique seed means a unique number for the first iteration of the PRG but I don't know what is the max seed the prg would take before repeating. Assume there's no memory to store all the numbers.

Comment: "considered a kind of block cipher" - if you're planning to use this for any sort of cryptographic purpose, **don't**.

Comment: just using it to generate non repeating random but curious if it fit the description for a block cipher.

Comment: What requirements do you have for "randomness"? Does it have to be good enough for simulations? Cryptography? Does it just need to be nonrepeating? How big is `MAX`?

Comment: randomness is when num is indistinguishable from a uniform distributed set of all numbers in range of 0...Max. Not necessary for simulation or cryptography. It needs to be non repeating assume max is 78364164095 .

Comment: You should update the question to make it clear exactly what you are after, and which constraints you have. To me it seems you would like some kind of generator function that, for each iteration, yields a random number. This random number is in the range [0..MAX] and numbers can not be repeated. Is this correct?

Comment: yes that's what I want. with an added memory restriction. I'll update the description to make it more clear. tnx.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
input = set()
for i in range(MAX):
    input.add(random.randrange(x,y))
print input
```

with in the range of x and y it will select some random values. W/o repetition means you can use set. so i am adding those values to set.

just make a try this one.

Answer (score 1):

The random module has a [sample function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html), which is predicated on producing `unique elements`. It is used as in the following example:

```
random_list = random.sample(xrange(10000000), 60) 
# generates a list of 60 random numbers in the 
# range 0 to 10000000 without repetition
```

But, do be aware that it will throw an exception if the length of the list is greater than the size of the population, e.g.

```
random_list = random.sample(xrange(5), 60 # you will get a ValueError here
```

Comment: "do be aware that it will repeat if the length of the list is greater than the size of the population" - no it won't. It'll raise a `ValueError`. Why did you think it would repeat?

Comment: Also, you can't sample from `5`.

Comment: @user1144251 You are looking for the `random.shuffle`, like I have shown in my answer.

Comment: This works fine for a small set. But for a large number it won't work ie: random.sample(range(78364164095),78364164095)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the numbers within a particular range,

1. either we have to store the generated random numbers and compare them against the newly generated random number

   ```
   import random
   result = []

   # hash values of numbers between -5 to 256 are the same as the
   # numbers themselves. So, whatever may be the order, set will have them
   # in the sorted order. So, `result` cannot be a `set` here.

   for x in range (0, 10):
       num = random.randint(0, 10)
       while num in result:
           num = random.randint(0, 10)
       result.append(num)
   print result
   ```
2. or we can generate the list and shuffle it like this

   ```
   data = range(10)
   import random
   random.shuffle(data)
   print data
   ```

   since you already have the population as a list and `random.shuffle` is an in-place operation, the result doesn't have to be stored in a separate list.

Comment: assume that there's not enough memory to store everything in memory.

Comment: @user1144251 Then how are you going to generate the random numbers and store it?

Comment: First way should use set, not list. List (vector) needs O(N) time to find if it has an item, while for hash-based set it's O(1) (on average).

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko hash values of numbers between -5 to 256 are the same as the numbers themselves. So, whatever may be the order, set will have them in the sorted order. So, we cannot use `set` here.

Comment: not storing the random number just printing it out (streaming it) no storage.

Comment: @user1144251 How big the list is going to be? Second approach should work fine for you.

Comment: @thefourtheye, we can just print (or yield from a function) every number before `result.append(num)` (`result.add(num)`).

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko Well, still we have to add it to `result` :) So, it doesn't matter if we yield values before appending or return all values at once.