# Python generating a range of numbers that have no same digits & unique

Tags: python

i am trying to figure out how to generate a list of numbers that are not only unique but also have no similar digits
The purpose is to crack sample hashes using crypt, what i know is the passwords are unique, no repeating digits and up to 6 digits

Example>

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...120, 123,124,125,126,127... 123456,123457...]
```

so 122 or 123451 or 12345673 because there will be repeating numbers

my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from os import getuid
from crypt import crypt
import time

# all initialisation here
password = range(1000000)
# all initialisation ends here

def VerifyHash(shadowHashes, salt, user):
    # crypt("Message", "Salt")
    for i in password:
        if (shadowHashes == crypt(str(i),salt)):
            print "Password of %s is " % user + str(i)
            break
        else:
            pass

def main():
    with open('shadow.txt') as p:
            for line in p:
                shadowList = line
                shadowHashes = shadowList.split(':')[1]
                user = shadowList.split(':')[0]
                salt = shadowHashes[:12]
                VerifyHash(shadowHashes,salt,user)  

main()
```

for now i am using range(1000000) and it works but is inefficient because the numbers i'm comparing to are unique with no repeating digits so i want to make my python program more efficient

Please point me in the right direction

Comment: Please include your code; it'll help us help you much better.

Comment: I am curious to see how you actually check for repeating digits.

Comment: To compare for repeating digits use `len(str(i)) == len(set(str(i)))`

Comment: Check out this post: [How to generate a range of random numbers in python without repetition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744963/how-to-generate-a-range-of-random-numbers-in-python-without-repetition)

Comment: @joelgoldstick I was about to post when I saw you already commented with something similar

Comment: Somehow I fail to see the connection between your code and your question...

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I saw your post.  Leave it up.  It got upvoted, and wrapped the test in a generator, so I think it is a good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the length of the number when represented as a string is the same when the digits in the number are placed in a set:

```
def unique_count():
    for i in range(1000000):
        if len(str(i)) == len(set(str(i))):
            yield i
```

The set eliminates duplicate digits, so numbers that do not have duplicated digits will pass the condition.

Comment: This is works but is *hugely* wasteful as it'll go on to test 10k times more numbers than need to be produced, and as a result is about 3 times slower at generating the first 10000 numbers from my solution, getting slower and slower as the numbers get bigger. Note that you can [calculate the number of digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189800/length-of-an-integer-in-python) rather than use a set. Not that that'll help avoid the huge wastage.

Comment: (and apologies, I had at first tested with `range()` on Python 2, rather than `xrange()`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters No qualms. Thanks for the digit count alternative. You are right about the frequency of a number being skipped increasing with the size of the numbers. I didn't give this much thought. I bet other users who search this question will find your solution a far more efficient alternative

Answer (score 3):

Use `itertools.permutations()` on an increasing number of repeated digits, up to 9, combining these with all digits between 1 and 9 (to prevent generating numbers with a leading 0).

```
from itertools import permutations

def generate_unique_numbers():
    yield 0
    for i in range(10):
        for leading in '123456789':
            if not i:  # 1-digit numbers
                yield int(leading)
                continue
            remaining_digits = '0123456789'.replace(leading, '')
            for combo in permutations(remaining_digits, i):
                yield int(leading + ''.join(combo))
```

This generates all such valid numbers without having to skip anything. There are 8877691 such numbers, ranging from 0 to 9876543210:

```
>>> sum(1 for _ in generate_unique_numbers())
8877691
>>> next(generate_unique_numbers())
0
>>> for i in generate_unique_numbers(): pass
...
>>> i
9876543210
```

A few samples of the output:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> gen = generate_unique_numbers()
>>> list(islice(gen, 15))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> list(islice(gen, 150, 165))
[204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 230]
>>> list(islice(gen, 100000, 100015))
[542319, 542360, 542361, 542367, 542368, 542369, 542370, 542371, 542376, 542378, 542379, 542380, 542381, 542386, 542387]
>>> list(islice(gen, 1000000, 1000015))
[31279056, 31279058, 31279064, 31279065, 31279068, 31279084, 31279085, 31279086, 31279405, 31279406, 31279408, 31279450, 31279456, 31279458, 31279460]
```

This method is easily faster than generating all numbers with `range(9876543211)` then filtering out those with repeated digits (which is what Moses Koledoye is doing):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> def consume_n(it, n): next(islice(it, n, n), None)
...
>>> timeit('consume_n(gen(), 10000)', 'from __main__ import consume_n, unique_count as gen', number=100)
1.825788974761963
>>> timeit('consume_n(gen(), 10000)', 'from __main__ import consume_n, generate_unique_numbers as gen', number=100)
0.6307981014251709
```

The above code generates just the first 10000 numbers for each approach, and repeats those tests 100 times. My approach is easily 3 times faster!

Increase the count (and adjust the number of repetitions down to keep it manageable), and the contrast grows:

```
>>> timeit('consume_n(gen(), 100000)', 'from __main__ import consume_n, unique_count as gen', number=10)
4.125269889831543
>>> timeit('consume_n(gen(), 100000)', 'from __main__ import consume_n, generate_unique_numbers as gen', number=10)
0.6416079998016357
```

Now the difference has grown to 6x faster. Generating the first million numbers just once takes *23 seconds* with the `range` version, .67 seconds with the above generator:

```
>>> timeit('consume_n(gen(), 1000000)', 'from __main__ import consume_n, unique_count as gen', number=1)
23.268329858779907
>>> timeit('consume_n(gen(), 1000000)', 'from __main__ import consume_n, generate_unique_numbers as gen', number=1)
0.6738729476928711
```

And the further along the series you go, the more natural numbers must be skipped and the speed difference only grows further; all numbers in the range 8800000000-8899999999 must be skipped for example, and the `range()` approach will test *all* of those. That's 100 million wasted cycles!

The generator can produce all possible such numbers in 6.7 seconds on my laptop:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> def consume(it): deque(it, maxlen=0)
...
>>> timeit('consume(gen())', 'from __main__ import consume, generate_unique_numbers as gen', number=1)
6.6731719970703125
```

I didn't dare test how long the `range()` approach takes; there are just under 9 million such numbers, but the `range()` approach will test close to 10 billion possibilities, 10000 times more numbers than needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! appreciate it, tried it but realized @Moses Koledoye's code is shorter and does the same thing! (:

Comment: @CwhatC: Added performance numbers. You are free to go with Moses' approach, but it'll take **way** longer to complete. You wanted something more efficient you said?

Comment: i will test out your method now, thanks for the feedback! i really appreciate the help and will try to learn as much as possible about the 2 approaches

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generate function below for a maximum number i then it will generate a liste of digits smaller then i unique, and without a digit repeated.

```
def isDigitsRepeated(integer):
    n = str(integer)
    digits = []
    for digit in n:
        if digit in digits:
            return True
        digits += [digit]
    return False

def generate(maximum):
    lst = []
    for x in range(maximum):
        if not isDigitsRepeated(x):
            lst += [x]
    return lst
```